# MDIsubwindow inside mdi subwindow Qt

Tags: qt, mdi, qwidget

I only wants to know if it is possible to do in QT what I'm imaging:
I want to open several different Windows (lets say widgets) inside several MIDsubwindows. So the MDIsubwindows functionality permits to open different files at the same time inside the MDIarea. Now, I want to put inside each MDIsubwindow diferentes Qwidgets (or another layer or MDIsubwindow) and have the possibility of changing separetely the size these Qwindows (and tile them) inside each MIDsubwindows. That is, A separately behaviour of each MDIsubwindow.

If this is posible, may you give some guides, links or documentations.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sure that's possible, QMDIsubwindow it's nothing more then just specialised QWidget, so you are free to put any content inside.. let's say QScrollArea and then you can put any of you 'sub-sub' windows.